# Error: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0 my dialect undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, nestjs

i get error Error: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0
how do i fix it?
I can't get the dialect and my settings seem to be wrong, help me fix it to connect to the database

### my sql.config.ts

```
import { registerAs } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Dialect } from 'sequelize';
import * as process from 'process';

export const sqlConfig = registerAs('database', () => ({
  dialect: 'mysql',
  logging: process.env.SQL_LOGGING === 'true' ? true : false,
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  autoLoadEntities: true,
  synchronize: true
}));
```

```
.env file
SQL_DIALECT=mysql
SQL_LOGGING=true
DATABASE_HOST=localhost
DATABASE_PORT=3306
DATABASE_USER=root
DATABASE_PASSWORD=12345
DATABASE_NAME=base
-
```

--
sequelizeConfig.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  SequelizeModuleOptions,
  SequelizeOptionsFactory,
} from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { User } from "../users/user.model";

@Injectable()
export class SequelizeConfigService implements SequelizeOptionsFactory {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {}

  createSequelizeOptions(): SequelizeModuleOptions {
    const {
      sql: { dialect, logging, host, port, username, password, database },
    } = this.configService.get('database');

    console.log('dialect:',dialect);

    return {
      dialect,
      logging,
      host,
      port,
      username,
      password,
      database,
      models:[User],
      autoLoadModels: true,
      synchronize: true,
      define: { charset:'utf8', collate:'utf8_general_ci' }
    };
  }
}
```

I need to connect to the base

Comment: If nestjs is generating SQL, show us the generated SQL, plus other things like `SHOW CREATE TABE`.